# Getting the Arizona Standard Time in .net

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I have an application in which time zones are treated as string, by using the system name so we can make an actual `System.TimeZoneInfo` object by doing:

```
var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
```

Such values are persisted to DB, now we are facing an issue where one such object is requested to be on `Arizona Time` which is not a standard timezone. From what I have investigated the `Arizona Time` changes Time Zones due to the fact that it doesn't observes "Day Light Savings".

I am looking for a way to set one value in DB so that there is no need to change it according to day light savings changes.

Is there a way to do this?

Even if I have to change a bit the code to get the `TimeZoneInfo` object. What really matters to me is a way to determine the actual timezone corresponding to `Arizona Time`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## About Arizona time zones

From [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/us/arizona-no-dst.html):

> There is a common misconception that Arizona is on Pacific Daylight
>   Time (PDT) during the summer and on Mountain Standard Time (MST)
>   during the winter. Because MST and PDT have the same UTC offset of
>   minus 7 hours (UTC-7), Arizona has the same local time as neighboring
>   states California and Nevada during the summer season. **Although the
>   time is the same, Arizona uses standard time (MST) all year**.
>   “Daylight” time zones, such as MDT, are mostly used for areas that
>   switch to DST every year

IANA (tz database) time zone database contains two time zones for Arizona:

- *America/Phoenix* (Mountain Standard Time - Arizona, except Navajo), which does **not** observe daylight saving changes (DST), and
- *America/Shiprock*, which observes DST.

## Arizona time zones in .NET

Depending on your users' exact location in Arizona, you should use either *America/Phoenix* or *America/Shiprock* time zone, so you will need two values in the database. However, if you try to get time zones with `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` using tz database names, you will get `System.TimeZoneNotFoundException`.

In order to get Arizona time zone that does not observe DST (*America/Phoenix*), you can use:

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Mountain Standard Time")
```

In order to get Arizona time zone that does observe DST (*America/Shiprock*), you can use:

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time")
```

So, you would have both ids in your database, `US Mountain Standard Time` and `Mountain Standard Time`, or alternatively some other strings that you would later map to these .NET time zone ids.

Check out [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/), it can help you a lot when it comes to dealing with date, time and time zones.

And finally, here is a sample program (with NodaTime) that demonstrates the difference between .NET *US Mountain Standard Time* (*America/Phoenix*, Arizona without DST) and *Mountain Standard Time* (*America/Shiprock*, Arizona with DST).

```cs
using System;

using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.TimeZones;

namespace TimeZoneExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Arizona without daylight saving time (TZ: America/Phoenix)
            var mstWithoutDstTz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Mountain Standard Time");

            // Arizona with daylight saving time (TZ: America/Shiprock)
            var mstWithDstTz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time");

            // NodaTime BclDateTimeZone for Arizona without daylight saving time
            var mstWithoutDstNodaTz = BclDateTimeZone.FromTimeZoneInfo(mstWithoutDstTz);

            // NodaTime BclDateTimeZone for Arizona with daylight saving time
            var mstWithDstNodaTz = BclDateTimeZone.FromTimeZoneInfo(mstWithDstTz);

            // January 1, 2017, 15:00, local winter date
            var localWinterDate = new LocalDateTime(2017, 01, 01, 15, 00);

            // NodaTime ZonedDateTime for Arizona without daylight saving time: January 1, 2017, 15:00
            var winterTimeWithoutDst = mstWithoutDstNodaTz.AtStrictly(localWinterDate);

            // NodaTime ZonedDateTime for Arizona with daylight saving time: January 1, 2017, 15:00
            var winterTimeWithDst = mstWithDstNodaTz.AtStrictly(localWinterDate);

            // Both time zones have the same time during winter
            Console.WriteLine($"Winter w/o DST: {winterTimeWithoutDst}"); // 2017-01-01T15:00:00 US Mountain Standard Time (-07)
            Console.WriteLine($"Winter w/ DST: {winterTimeWithDst}"); // 2017-01-01T15:00:00 Mountain Standard Time (-07)

            // add 180 days to get June 30, 2017
            var sixMonthsToSummer = Duration.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(180, 0, 0, 0));

            // During summer, e.g. on June 30, Arizona without daylight saving time is 1 hour behind.
            Console.WriteLine($"Summer w/o DST: {winterTimeWithoutDst + sixMonthsToSummer}"); // 2017-06-30T15:00:00 US Mountain Standard Time (-07)
            Console.WriteLine($"Summer w/ DST: {winterTimeWithDst + sixMonthsToSummer}"); // 2017-06-30T16:00:00 Mountain Standard Time (-06)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to create a custom time zone representing "Arizona Time" which has a constant offset from UTC regardless the date of the year.

If so, you should be able to use the static method

```
TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone
```

Just set the TimeSpan to the number of hours from UTC that you need it to be (-7 hours from what I can tell).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb309898(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT: You might also have some success by simply using the named timezone

```
"US Mountain Standard Time"
```

which should represent the same.